# ADFS. Third Party True Claim Rule needed to return `domain\user`

Tags: exchange, adfs

I have configured Claims Provider Trust in ADFS and I am getting only `Email` in `NameID`. I can not make changes to Third party Claims Provider Trust, so I have to get `WindowsAccountName` using the Email Address, which I received in NameID from Third Party IDP and forward it to Outlook Web Access (on-premise).

I've found that when I use the following Claim Rule, sign-in works, but only if the user's UPN and email address match. If there are differences between them (e.g. sAMAccountName=jdoe; UPN=jdoe@contoso.com; Email=**Jonathan.Doe**@contoso.com), the value forwarded to Exchange causes an error to be thrown.

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] == "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer = "AD AUTHORITY", OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = regexreplace(c.Value, "(?<user>[^\@]+)\@(.+)", "contoso\${user}"), ValueType = c.ValueType);
```

How can I look up a user via their email address, and return their`WindowsAccountName` in `domain\username` format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone runs into this issue. You need two rules.

**Rule #1: sAMAccountName to temp**
This tells ADFS to look in ActiveDirectory and return any accounts where the UPN or Email address matches. Then the rule stores the value into a temporary variable which we'll use in the next rule.

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] == "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("claims:temp/attribute1"), query = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(userPrincipalName={0})(mail={0})));sAMAccountName;contoso\adfs_service_account", param = c.Value);
```

NB. The `contoso\adfs_service_account` is important. ADFS needs this to auto-discover a Domain Controller. Use ANY AD account, just so long as it is a real account.

**Rule #2: temp to WindowsAccountName**
The above rule only returns the sAMAccountName, not the domain. In my case I only had one domain. As such, I hardcoded it below.

```
c:[Type == "claims:temp/attribute1"] => issue(Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer = "AD AUTHORITY", OriginalIssuer = "https://contoso.verify.ibm.com/saml/sps/saml20ip/saml20", Value = "contoso\" + c.Value);
```